# Posting A Clickable Graphic On My Facebook Wall Via Java and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a script that has been working for about 7 months now and today it just stopped working.

It allows my members to pick a graphic from a pull down, add their own URL, Name, Description and Caption. Then they press a button, it opens a popup from Facebook and shows the graphic, Name, Description and Caption. They then click the Post button and it posts on their own Facebook Wall. The graphic when clicked goes to the URL they enter.

Here is the code I have been using:

```
 <script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({appId: 'MY_ID_TAKEN_OUT', status: true, cookie: true,
xfbml: true});
};
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#share_button').click(function(e){
var my_images=$('#my_images').val();
var url=$('#url2').val();
var caption=$('#caption').val();
var description=$('#description').val();
var name=$('#name').val();
e.preventDefault();
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: name,
link: url,
picture: my_images,
caption: caption,
description: description,
message: '',
});
});
});
</script>
```

I am very aware that they upgraded to version 2.10 today, but that should not have affected me because I am using version 2.8 which is still good according to Facebook.

I have also checked my API and it's fine as well.

What it's doing now instead of showing the image the member picks is it's just using a graphic from the website of the URL they enter. I need to to show the graphic they choose again and make it clickable so it goes to the URL they enter.

Here is the form code if you want it to test with:

```
<form  name="myForm" method="post">
<table width="450" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="140">
<b>Banner Ads:</b><br />
Facebook Banner: </td><td><SELECT NAME="image" id='my_images'>
<OPTION value="">-- Please Select One --</OPTION>
<OPTION value="http://www.imagefully.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Happy-Birthday-Gift-And-Wishees-Graphic-Share-On-Facebook-Wall.jpg">Test Image</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="140">
<tr><td width="140" class="optionallanding">
URL For Page:</td>
<td class="optionallanding"><input type="text" size="35" maxlength="100" name="url2" value="" id="url2" placeholder="Must Include http://" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td class="optionallanding">&nbsp;</td><td class="optionallanding">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td width="140">
Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" size="35" maxlength="40" name="name" value="" id="name" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td width="140">
Description:</td>
<td><input type="text" size="35" maxlength="40" name="description" id="description" value="" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td width="140">
Caption:</td>
<td><input type="text" size="35" maxlength="40" name="caption" id="caption" value="" />
</td></tr>
</table>
<p /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="share_button" value="Post To Facebook"><br /><br />
</form>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You need to set og-tags on the URL. https://techcrunch.com/2017/07/18/facebook-link-preview-modification/

Comment: _“but that should not have affected me because I am using version 2.8 which is still good according to Facebook.”_ - no, that change affects all API versions. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations